# I can't run iptables inside the container CENTOS - 7.9 OR ROCKYlinux 8.8

Tags: docker, iptables

every image centos-7 or rocky-linux 8.7+ that I download on my ubuntu.2204 machine when I build it with all the packages I need, the only one that I can't run when I save this image and load it into docker on another machine, is iptables when trying to run iptables -nL I receive the message:

on my docker file i made install iptables and installed but not work after make image!

```
# iptables -nL
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

The problem only happens if I export the image, I've already tried with official and unofficial images from Dockerhub, could anyone help me?

```
docker run -p 1555:1555/tcp -dti --restart always --name mycontainer --hostname mycontainer-net --network mynetwork --ip 172.18.0.3 --privileged custom-centos-iptables
```

Answer (score 1):

Containers run with a restricted set of privileges. Inside a container, by default, you are not able to change the network configuration -- this includes interface configuration, routes, and iptables.

If you need to run iptables in a container, you can run that container with elevated privileges. To grant just those privileges necessary for network configuration:

```
docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN ...
```

To remove *all* restrictions:

```
docker run --privileged ...
```

Be aware that running a container with `--privileged` removes much of the isolation that generally exists between a container and the host. You should never do this with containers that offer remotely accessible services.

Comment: hi, bro i delete and re-create container with "--cap-add NET_ADMIN"

after docker exec -it... 

iptables -nL
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.